# How to select data from array of json object in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Data I have:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"code": "SM", "place": "San Mateo, CA, USA"},{"code": "IND", "place": "Indianapolis, IN, USA"}] |

What I want it to be transformed as:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | San Mateo, CA, USA; Indianapolis, IN, USA |

This is as far as I can get (table is just a sample)

```
SELECT 
INDEX, 
PARSE_JSON(f.THIS),
ARRAY_TO_STRING(PARSE_JSON(f.THIS),';')
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json('[{"code": "SM","place": "San Mateo, CA, USA"},{"code": "IND","place": "Indianapolis, IN, USA"}]'))) f LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close:

```sql
SELECT 
seq, 
listagg(f.value:place, '; ')
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json('[{"code": "SM","place": "San Mateo, CA, USA"},{"code": "IND","place": "Indianapolis, IN, USA"}]'))) f 
group by seq

-- San Mateo, CA, USA; Indianapolis, IN, USA
```